# How to use std::normal_distribution

Tags: c++

I am an experienced C programmer that is occasionally forced to use a little bit of C++.

I need to generate random numbers from a normal distribution with a variety of means and variances. If I had a C function that did this called `normal(float mean, float var)` then I could write the following code:

```
int i;
float sample;
for(i = 0;i < 1000;i++)
{
  sample = normal(mean[i],variance[i]);
  do_something_with_this_value(sample);
}
```

Note that there is a different mean and variance for each value of i.

C does not contain a function called normal, but C++ does, well actually its called std::normal_distribution. Unfortunately my C++ is not good enough to understand the syntax in the documentation. Can anyone tell me how to achieve the functionality of my C code but using std::normal_distribution.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution

Comment: @Arunmu - yes I was looking at exactly that page, but I do not understand it... all that "<>" stuff is a mystery to me.

Comment: @Mick That `<>` syntax signifies use of *templates* which are incredibly powerful and underpin the majority of the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of the page. Btw the "<>" bits are template arguments.

Comment: Looks like you have some reading to do, but in general the pattern is as follows: Create and seed a random engine (E.G. The engine `std::mt19937` and seed it with `std::random_device`.) Now create your distribution object (I.E. `std::normal_distribution<float> dist(mean, deviation);`). Now call your distribution with the generator as the argument. `dist(gen);`.

Comment: @Jasper Juhl: the example seems to be arranged to use a fixed mean and variance (the "5,2" bit) - I can not work out how to make these variables instead of constants..

Comment: @Mick Consider creating a distribution as a low cost action and just create a new distribution for every mean / standard deviation you want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::normal_distribution` isn't function but templated class

you can use it like this:

```
#include <random>

int main(int, char**)
{
    // random device class instance, source of 'true' randomness for initializing random seed
    std::random_device rd; 

    // Mersenne twister PRNG, initialized with seed from previous random device instance
    std::mt19937 gen(rd()); 
    
    int i;
    float sample;
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        // instance of class std::normal_distribution with specific mean and stddev
        std::normal_distribution<float> d(mean[i], stddev[i]); 

        // get random number with normal distribution using gen as random source
        sample = d(gen); 

        // profit
        do_something_with_this_value(sample); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer, that said It looks a bit neater if you space out your code and put the comments on their own lines.

Comment: I still wondering how to control the boundaries (min and max) of the generated numbers. For example, according to this diagram on Wikipedia ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Normal_Distribution_PDF.svg ), a mean of 0.0 and a variance of 1.0 should gives me a result between 0.0 and 0.4, right ? But after a test, it is not always the case, sometimes the return value is out of this range. Maybe there is something I don't understand into the mathematical part.

Comment: isnt it suppose to be standard deviation and not variance

Comment: @Ant0nin no, a normal distribution always gives you a number between -infinity and +infinity. Very high (or very low) numbers are just vanishingly unlikely